# SQL Server Management Studio Color Schemes?

Tags: themes, sql-server-2008, color-profiles, sql-management-studio

Is there a way to apply color schemes and themes to SQL Server Management Studio?  I really enjoy the ones for Visual Studio 2005/2008/2010 and would love to have something like that.

Color Schemes for Visual Studio:

- [Create and share Visual Studio color schemes](http://studiostyles.info/)

**Edit:**

- I want to add that I mean color schemes of the editor, not the actual window/toolbar/borders etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With some googling, I came across:
[Color Schemes in SQL 2005 Management Studio](http://winterdom.com/2007/10/colorschemesinsql2005managementstudio).

From the site:

> **Enter VSColorsToSql**
>
> This is a simple utility I wrote last night that will port your current VS2005 Fonts And Colors Settings (just for the code editor, mind you) to Management Studio. It's nothing fancy, so all it does is copy some registry settings around.

I'd love to have something simpler.  I wonder if this is the best way thus far.

Comment: The program doesn't work in Windows 7 unfortunately.

Comment: Just in case someone stumbles on this and wants it to work. It will work in Windows 7 if you change the registry path constants in code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way. Themes, for the window and associated, like [the VS themes package](http://blog.bagearon.com/2012/03/sql-server-management-studio-2012-color-themes-extension-support/):

> Note the use of the [dark expression theme](http://www.nerdpad.com/visual-studio/visual-studio-2010-dark-expression-blend-color-theme).
>
> The source [VS 2010 plugin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378/).
>
> Unzip this to your SQL Server Management Studio path in the extensions
>   folder, for me was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Extensions`
>
> Start/restart SSMS, and customize the theme as necessary.